# How to remove timestamp in date using ionic 2?

Tags: angular, calendar, ionic2

I am displaying the calendar with the help of this plugin [Ionic 2 Calender](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar). In this i am displaying the calendar in the button.The calendar is displaying date with timestamp, however i only want to display only date.

`.ts`

```
onTimeSelected(ev) {
     let data=this.isToday;
     this.viewCtrl.dismiss({"selecteddate":data});
     this.navCtrl.push(HomePage,{
     selecteddate:ev.selectedTime 
   });
}
```

`.html`

```
<calendar [calendarMode]="calendar.mode"       
          [currentDate]="calendar.currentDate" 
          (onCurrentDateChanged)="onCurrentDateChanged($event)" 
          [markDisabled]="markDisabled" 
          (onTitleChanged)="onViewTitleChanged($event)" 
          (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)" 
          [eventSource]="eventSource" 
          autoSelect="false" 
          step="30"> 
</calendar>
```

Comment: can you add your html code?

Comment: <calendar
              [calendarMode]="calendar.mode"
              [currentDate]="calendar.currentDate"
              (onCurrentDateChanged)="onCurrentDateChanged($event)"
              [markDisabled]="markDisabled"
              (onTitleChanged)="onViewTitleChanged($event)"
              (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)"
               [eventSource]="eventSource"
              autoSelect="false"
              step="30">
    </calendar>

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using an [angular 2 date pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html)

In the `.html` you can add the date pipe to your `[currentDate]` attribute, which will transform the timestamp date into the format that you would like to use ( view link above to see all format types).

```
[currentDate]="calendar.currentDate | date:'dd MMM y'"
```

There is also the [format options](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar#options) associated with the module itself. Which seem specific to formatting the date in its module specific attributes.

Comment: previously i had tried what you had mentioned.But there is no change in output

Comment: Which one , the date pipe or the ionic 2 calendar format options?

Comment: I don't tried in pipe i tried what you mentioned in that answer